# Rebus Puzzle Help!

Tags: rebus

Figured out the majority of the puzzle I think. There's just a couple things stumping me. Like the knights for one.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, I solved the knights ;) Hope this helps

Comment: If any of Jay's/ mine answer helps, you can accept the answer by pressing the tick button next to our answers. You can choose only one of us though, up to you ;)

Comment: Just wondering, where'd you get this ^_^ I live them and want to do more :D

Answer (score 20):

Based on @Jay's answer, the entire answer should be:

> “Out of all the things I have lost, I miss my mind the most.” - Mark Twain

I'll edit the explanations for later

> Of  (Wo**of**)  credits @Jay
>  All  (B**all**)  credits @Jay
>  The (Tic Tac Toe - Tick - Tack, then with O = H)  credits @Jay
>  **Things** (KNIGHTS --> K=1, N=2, I=3, G=4, H=5, T=6, S=7 ==> Roman numerals above = 6-5-3-2-4-7 ==>**T-H-I-N-G-S**)
>  I've (Hive - H)  credits @Jay
>  Lost (**Lo**bo + Ne**st** - Bone) Thanks @squishycoast  credits @Jay
>  I (Mathematical symbol)  credits @Jay
>  Miss (**Mi** as in Do, Re, Mi + **S** + **S**)  credits @Jay
>  My  (Money - One)    credits @Jay
>  Mind  (M in D)  credits @Jay
>  The   (T + He)  credits @Jay
>  **Most** (eye = I, bee = B, rot19 would turn i to b, therefore rot19(TVZA) = **MOST**)

Comment: quite some bit of thought you've put into this I must say... so has @Jay.. loved it.

Answer (score 18):

Partial answer

> Of  (Wo**of**)
>  All  (B**all**)
>  The (Tic Tac Toe - Tick - Tack, then with O = H)
>  ?
>  I've (Hive - H)
>  Lost (**Lo**bo + Ne**st** - Bone) Thanks @squishycoast
>  I (Mathematical symbol)
>  Miss (**Mi** as in Do, Re, Mi + **S** + **S**)
>  My  (Money - One)
>  Mind  (M in D)
>  The   (T + He)
>  ?

I believe the final phrase will be

> "Of all the things I've lost, I miss my mind the most"

Comment: your answer was first for the entire answer for 3 mins... , you should get the tick... +1

Comment: It's not finished yet

Comment: Yes it is, by me ;)

Comment: Nicely done with the missing ones

Comment: Very nice on those last ones!